# Building wheel for scipy (setup.py) ... error

Tags: python, scipy

In http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html, there is an project which needs me to install something below(python 2.7):

```html
numpy==1.13.3
scikit-learn==0.19.0
scipy==0.19.1
Theano==0.7.0
```

but when I start a new environment on anaconda and try to install it ,I got this long long error:

```html
(neural) C:\Users\lenovo>pip install -r C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\neural-networks-and-deep-learning-master\requirements.txt
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Requirement already satisfied: numpy==1.13.3 in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages (from -r C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\neural-networks-and-deep-learning-master\requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.13.3)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn==0.19.0 in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages (from -r C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\neural-networks-and-deep-learning-master\requirements.txt (line 2)) (0.19.0)
Collecting scipy==0.19.1
  Using cached scipy-0.19.1.tar.gz (14.1 MB)
Collecting Theano==0.7.0
  Downloading Theano-0.7.0.tar.gz (2.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.0 MB 95 kB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: scipy, Theano
  Building wheel for scipy (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'd:\anaconda\envs\neural\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-lbmv2a\\scipy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-lbmv2a\\scipy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\temp\pip-wheel-bcvgut'
       cwd: c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-lbmv2a\scipy\
  Complete output (109 lines):
  lapack_opt_info:
  lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['d:\\anaconda\\envs\\neural\\lib', 'C:\\', 'd:\\anaconda\\envs\\neural\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  openblas_lapack_info:
  d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:655: UserWarning: Specified path c:\opt\64\lib is invalid.
    return self.get_paths(self.section, key)
    libraries libopenblas_v0.2.20_mingwpy not found in []
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\libs
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_info:
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries satlas,satlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\libs
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\libs
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_info:
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\libs
    libraries lapack_atlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\libs
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
      Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
      the ATLAS environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  lapack_info:
    libraries lapack not found in ['d:\\anaconda\\envs\\neural\\lib', 'C:\\', 'd:\\anaconda\\envs\\neural\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    self.calc_info()
    NOT AVAILABLE

  Running from scipy source directory.
  non-existing path in 'scipy\\integrate': 'quadpack.h'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-lbmv2a\scipy\setup.py", line 416, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-lbmv2a\scipy\setup.py", line 412, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-lbmv2a\scipy\setup.py", line 336, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('scipy')
    File "d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1029, in add_subpackage
      caller_level = 2)
    File "d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 998, in get_subpackage
      caller_level = caller_level + 1)
    File "d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('linalg')
    File "d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1029, in add_subpackage
      caller_level = 2)
    File "d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 998, in get_subpackage
      caller_level = caller_level + 1)
    File "d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
      raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
  numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scipy
  Running setup.py clean for scipy
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'd:\anaconda\envs\neural\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-lbmv2a\\scipy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-lbmv2a\\scipy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
       cwd: c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-lbmv2a\scipy
  Complete output (9 lines):

  `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:

    - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
    - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                        files that aren't checked into the git repo)

  Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).

  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for scipy
  Building wheel for Theano (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for Theano: filename=Theano-0.7.0-py2-none-any.whl size=1797792 sha256=fd595aaa031f6068b16db3799bcec9070ab1e346a10e1f2a99fb5f67f0863415
  Stored in directory: c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\65\44\26\81e2eb68062962cfa030b4716acd672e97db5185d59f873985
Successfully built Theano
Failed to build scipy
Installing collected packages: scipy, Theano
  Attempting uninstall: scipy
    Found existing installation: scipy 1.2.3
    Uninstalling scipy-1.2.3:
      Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.2.3
    Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'd:\anaconda\envs\neural\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-lbmv2a\\scipy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-lbmv2a\\scipy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-1ngsyc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'd:\anaconda\envs\neural\Include\scipy'
         cwd: c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-lbmv2a\scipy\
    Complete output (118 lines):

    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['d:\\anaconda\\envs\\neural\\lib', 'C:\\', 'd:\\anaconda\\envs\\neural\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
    d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:655: UserWarning: Specified path c:\opt\64\lib is invalid.
      return self.get_paths(self.section, key)
      libraries libopenblas_v0.2.20_mingwpy not found in []
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in d:\anaconda\envs\neural\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['d:\\anaconda\\envs\\neural\\lib', 'C:\\', 'd:\\anaconda\\envs\\neural\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
      NOT AVAILABLE

    Running from scipy source directory.
    non-existing path in 'scipy\\integrate': 'quadpack.h'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-lbmv2a\scipy\setup.py", line 416, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-lbmv2a\scipy\setup.py", line 412, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-lbmv2a\scipy\setup.py", line 336, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('scipy')
      File "d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1029, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 998, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('linalg')
      File "d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1029, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 998, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 935, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found
    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of scipy
  Moving to d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\scipy-1.2.3.dist-info\
   from d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\~cipy-1.2.3.dist-info
  Moving to d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\scipy\
   from d:\anaconda\envs\neural\lib\site-packages\~cipy
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'd:\anaconda\envs\neural\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-lbmv2a\\scipy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-lbmv2a\\scipy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-1ngsyc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'd:\anaconda\envs\neural\Include\scipy' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have already installed the whl of scipy in python2.7.but I got this error again
I have no idea about it.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might wish to look at this part of the error:   `Rolling back uninstall of scipy`

Comment: I would also go as far to say that `python 2.7` is not supported any more so many packages might not work for this. the current version is `3.10` which is one major version infront and 10 minor versions (at the point of writing)...